Lo4j2 class level logger's logging level not taking effect
I am bit confused why my log4j2 logging levels and appenders dont seem to work as I expect. Let me give the details.
Project Structure:

Main.java :
package com.my.sample.MySampleProject;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import com.my.sample.package2.MyPackage2Class;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class Main {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("Debug log message");
        logger.info("Info log message");
        logger.error("Error log message");
        
        MyPackage2Class classPack2 = new MyPackage2Class();
        classPack2.printStatement();

    }
} 

MyPackage2Class.java
package com.my.sample.package2;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;



public class MyPackage2Class {
    
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MyLoggerPackage2");
    
    public void printStatement() {
        logger.debug("Package2 Debug log message");
        logger.info("Package2 Info log message");
        logger.error("Package2 Error log message");
    }
    
    

    
}

log4j2.properties


# Direct log messages to STDOUT
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

# Direct to a file
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName = sample/logs/log4j2.log
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n


log4j.logger.MyLoggerPackage2=ERROR, STDOUT
log4j.additivity.MyLoggerPackage2=false

# Root Logger
rootLogger=INFO, STDOUT, LOGFILE

So basically root logger set to INFO level with appender STDOUT, LOGFILE
MyLoggerPackage2 logger set to ERROR level with appender STDOUT with additivity false
So I should expect only ERROR level logs for MyPackage2Class  in console only.
But in console I see:
[INFO ] 2024-06-19 11:19:12.769 [main] Main - Info log message
[ERROR] 2024-06-19 11:19:12.772 [main] Main - Error log message
[INFO ] 2024-06-19 11:19:12.779 [main] MyLoggerPackage2 - Package2 Info log message
[ERROR] 2024-06-19 11:19:12.779 [main] MyLoggerPackage2 - Package2 Error log message

In the logfile I see:
[INFO ] 2024-06-19 11:19:12.769 [main] Main - Info log message
[ERROR] 2024-06-19 11:19:12.772 [main] Main - Error log message
[INFO ] 2024-06-19 11:19:12.779 [main] MyLoggerPackage2 - Package2 Info log message
[ERROR] 2024-06-19 11:19:12.779 [main] MyLoggerPackage2 - Package2 Error log message

What mistake am I doing? A little explanation would be helpful.
I tried changing position of the rootLogger settings to the bottom, changing the root logger level (which is taking effect)
Thanks in advance.

These properties do not follow the Log4j 2 properties format:
log4j.logger.MyLoggerPackage2=ERROR, STDOUT
log4j.additivity.MyLoggerPackage2=false

You should use:
logger.0.name = com.my.sample.package2
logger.0.additivity = false
logger.0.level = ERROR
logger.0.appenderRef.0.ref = STDOUT

Personally I wouldn't recommend the Java properties configuration format to anyone (check the list of syntax rules on our website). You should consider switching to the default XML format, which as a bonus comes with an XSD:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration xmlns="https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns/log4j-config-2.xsd">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="LOGFILE" fileName="sample/logs/log4j2.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="ERROR">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="LOGFILE"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="MyLoggerPackage2"
            level="ERROR"
            additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Logger>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>

You can also use the YAML configuration format (with an additional Jackson dependency), which has a hierarchical structure as XML, but is less verbose (no closing tags).

Thank you. What is the 0 in the logger.0.name ?

Even after that (property file change, XML configuration not tried) both ERROR and INFO log from the MyPackage2Class is coming to both in the log file and console

The 0 is an arbitrary identifier, you can use anything else as long as it does not contain a dot ..
Sorry, I didn't notice that the name of your logger differs from the full class name.
I fixed the answer.
